shared ptr release core
gdb version: 4.9.2.
execution mode: multi threads.
Code1 occurs core:
  auto close_handle = [this, conn, &service_spec]() {
    FLUX_LOG(INFO, "close connection on response with spec: [%s]",
             service_spec.ToString().c_str());
    auto client_conn = static_cast<cygnet::HttpClientConnection*>(conn);
    auto conn_mgr = this->selected_conn_mgr_;
    conn_mgr->EndRequest(client_conn);
  };

After modified the core disappeared:
  auto close_handle = [this, conn, &service_spec]() {
    FLUX_LOG(INFO, "close connection on response with spec: [%s]",
             service_spec.ToString().c_str());
    auto client_conn = static_cast<cygnet::HttpClientConnection*>(conn);
    this->selected_conn_mgr_->EndRequest(client_conn);
  };

conn_mgr is a shared ptr, in code1 a shared ptr is created then destroyed. When I request my server concurrently. A core occured over shared_ptr stuff, the core info is as below:
#0  0x000000000099c8f0 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000005ae1f8 in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release (this=0x9b9020) at /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:149
#2  0x00000000005a3923 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count (this=0x7fca6cff7478, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:666
#3  0x00000000005a0d86 in std::__shared_ptr<flux::ConnectionManager, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr (this=0x7fca6cff7470, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:914
#4  0x00000000005a0dba in std::shared_ptr<flux::ConnectionManager>::~shared_ptr (this=0x7fca6cff7470, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:93
#5  0x00007fca898bfc98 in flux::CygnetHttpClient::<lambda()>::operator()(void) const (__closure=0x7fca6cff75c0)
    at build/debug64/flux/plugins/restful/cygnet_http_client/cygnet_http_client.cc:274

Does anyone know what happened?

Will the object that the shared pointer is pointing to be alive (not destructed) when your close_handle lambda is called? Can it be called simultaneously from multiple threads, leading to a data-race?

On another note, while you might use GDB for debugging, the problem is unlikely to be caused by GDB, so it shouldn't be tagged.

I think we need a [MCVE] I suspect that the first code suffers the same race condition, but you just haven't witnessed it yet.

Does EndRequest might nullify this->selected_conn_mgr_? if yes if later case, destruction might happen there, and in the former case, conn_mgr keep it alive to the end of the function.

@Someprogrammerdude, The obj is still alive. Check the difference between code 1 and code 2. the only difference is that I use the ptr of the obj directly in code 2 but copy the shared ptr out in code 1.

@Jarod42, end request would not nullify mgr.

@AndyG em... It's quite hard to reproduce it, the core occured after 5 mins I request the server(using the code piece) in nearly 20 qps.

That's the problem with undefined behavior, very small differences that might seem equivalent could cause large differences in behavior. A data-race, where to or more threads try to access the same resource simultaneously, is one common cause of UB (Undefined Behavior) in multi-threaded code.

My guess would be, there's a race with the destruction of the object that this points to. Or else, it's already destroyed, this is dangling, but its contents haven't been overwritten yet. The difference between code1 and code2 is that code1 accesses the shared pointer's control block, which I'm guessing is either in the process of being deallocated, or has been already. Whereas code2 does not.

Do you synchronize with your thread at shutdown? You don't want any of your threads to outlive this

Maybe ASAN + UBSAN might help. If this is indeed a problem where you nondet step on UB. If it is a race, then they wont help you, though.
